# Powermac gdbserver wrapper/How to attach IDA to powermac application?

Tags: ida, debugging, mach-o, powerpc

How do I debug a powermac application using gdbserver provided there is no gdbserver

I've tried compiling various version of gdb found in apple opensource -specifically the gdbserver part but it seems that the Apple developer never finished working on it.

Whenever I try using it it segment faults all over the place.

Answer (score 1):

If you can run it in QEMU, you can try connecting to the QEMU's GDB stub. Note that this will provide you the CPU-level view, with the OS kernel included, so it may take some work to get to the app's code.